QML Sidebar Animation on Mouse Hover Not Working with States and Transitions
I have created a sidebar in qml. which I want to show and hide it with animation on mouse hover.
I'm using MouseArea, states and transitions to do it and the MouseArea detects mouse hover, but animations is not working. I can't figure out what's the reason.
main.qml:
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item {
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: parent.width * 0.05
        height: parent.height

        Sidebar {
            id: sidebar
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}

Sidebar.qml:
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: sidebar
    property color color: "#578cad"
    property double sidebarWidth: parent.width
    state: "collapsed"

    states: [
        State {
            name: "collapsed"
            PropertyChanges { target: sidebar; x: -sidebar.width + sidebar.width * 0.05 }
        },
        State {
            name: "expanded"
            PropertyChanges { target: sidebar; x: 0 }
        }
    ]

    transitions: [
        Transition {
            from: "collapsed"
            to: "expanded"
            PropertyAnimation { target: sidebar; property: "x"; duration: 300 }
        },
        Transition {
            from: "expanded"
            to: "collapsed"
            PropertyAnimation { target: sidebar; property: "x"; duration: 300 }
        }
    ]

    Rectangle {
        id: sidebarRect
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "transparent"

        Canvas {
            anchors.fill: parent

            onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext("2d");
                ctx.reset();

                ctx.lineWidth = 1;
                ctx.strokeStyle = color
                ctx.fillStyle = color;

                drawSideBar(ctx);
            }
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true

            onEntered: {
                console.log("enter")
                sidebar.state = "expanded"
            }
            onExited: {
                console.log("exit")
                sidebar.state = "collapsed"
            }
        }
    }

    function drawSideBar(ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(0, height * 0.1);

        ctx.bezierCurveTo(0, height * 0.1 + (height * 0.1) * 0.7,
                          sidebarWidth, height * 0.1 + (height * 0.1) * 0.3,
                          sidebarWidth, height * 0.1 + height * 0.1);

        ctx.lineTo(sidebarWidth, height * 0.8);

        ctx.bezierCurveTo(sidebarWidth, height * 0.8 + (height * 0.1) * 0.7,
                          0, height * 0.8 + (height * 0.1) * 0.3,
                          0, height * 0.8 + height * 0.1);

        ctx.lineTo(0, height);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }
}


I don't know what you intended to do, but the QML has a Drawer component that you can use.
